# Samsung Galaxy Apollo (GT-I5801) doesn't connect to WiFi connection. What should O do?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-apollo

Currently my phone doesn't connect to WiFi connection, it always on and off everytime I open my WiFi connection.

What can be possible solutions or what do I need to check in order to connect my Samsung Galaxy Apollo (GT-I5801) to WiFi connection and to stick to on when I open my WiFi connection?

Answer (score 0):

Currently my phone doesn't connect to WiFi connection, it always on and off everytime I open my WiFi connection.

Solution for the i5801:

1. Go to *Settings → Wireless and Network → WiFi*
2. Use the menu button to open the *Advanced* option
3. Click on *Use static IP*
4. You will see IP address, Gateway, Netmask, DNS1, DNS2. Fill all these things and to see their value:

   1. left click on signal strength (left or right to battery or sound sign)
   2. right click on your network to which you connected
   3. you should see status; click on this
   4. now a page is open (wireless network connection status); here click on *details*
   5. now you should see IPv4 (IP address), IPv4 default gateway (gateway), IPv4 subnet mask (for netmask), IPv4 DNS servers (DNS1, DNS2)
5. Save all these setting by clicking on menu then save.

If this does not work check this also:

1. open 192.168.1.1
2. open *Wireless → Security check* (network authentication WPA personal auto)
3. after that your password
4. then next [WPA group rekey interval 3600 (in my case this is the problem in my modem here is 4 so i remove it and type 3600)]
5. after this (wpa/wapi encryption tkip+aes)
6. then save this setting.

Comment: Just formatted that "wall of text". I cannot try this out myself to confirm, but a short hint: I *guess* by *open 192.168.1.1* user43738 meant the settings on a Windows PC? Or what machine does that IP belong to? A router would make the most sense here. But I just updated the formatting of the answer, I didn't want to edit in my own thoughts and possibly introduce misinterpretations ;) // Apart from the formatting, this seems to be a valid and useful answer!